# JQuery Not selector not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a JQuery DOM object from a string of HTML.  I'm then trying to remove get only the objects that are not img's.

I'm using the not selector... but it's not working as I'm expecting,
The resultant object only includes the img tag and I'm not sure why.

Here's a snippet

```js
var HTMLString='<figure class="tmblr-full"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></figure><p>This is NOT the cat we are looking for! </p>';

var jqueryObjectFromHTMLString=$(HTMLString);

var jqueryObjectMinusImages=jqueryObjectFromHTMLString.not('img');

//The following outputs an image tag
console.log(jqueryObjectMinusImages.html());

//The following replaces the body with our jquery object that's not supposed to inclue an image
$('body').replaceWith(jqueryObjectMinusImages);
```

```css
.block{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.red{
  background:red;  
}

.blue{
  background:blue;  
}

.green{
  background:green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block red">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way is to just remove the images

```
var HTMLString='<figure class="tmblr-full"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></figure><p>This is NOT the cat we are looking for! </p>';

var $htmlObject=$(HTMLString);

$htmlObject.find('img').remove();
```

If you need to keep the original object intact you can also clone the object

```
var HTMLString='<figure class="tmblr-full"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></figure><p>This is NOT the cat we are looking for! </p>';

var $htmlObject=$(HTMLString);
var $htmlNoImages = $htmlObject.clone();
$htmlNoImages.find('img').remove();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a16rberw/2/

Comment: A side note on why .not('img') was not working. It will only check the top level children.  Any nested children are not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Let deconstruct your code. First, you make a jQuery object with a string. Your jQuery object then contains 2 elements, the `figure` and the `p`.

Then you use `.not` wich filter the current elements. It does **not** filter children. So your jQuery object after `.not` is still the same since it does not contains any `img`.

Then, you do `.html` on the stack. When using this function as a getter on a stack, it returns the **`innerHTML`** of the **first element** in the stack. in your case, it returns the `innerHTML` of the `figure` wich only contains the `img`.

If you want to remove the `img` in your jQuery element, you should use `.find('img').remove();`:

```js
var HTMLString='<figure class="tmblr-full"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></figure><p>This is NOT the cat we are looking for! </p>';

var jqueryObjectFromHTMLString=$(HTMLString);

var jqueryObjectMinusImages=$(HTMLString).clone();
jqueryObjectMinusImages.find('img').remove();

//The following replaces the body with our jquery object that's not supposed to inclue an image
$('body').replaceWith(jqueryObjectMinusImages);
```

```css
.block{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.red{
  background:red;  
}

.blue{
  background:blue;  
}

.green{
  background:green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block red">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your provided JSFiddle you call

```
$('body').replaceWith(jqueryObjectMinusImages);
```

When i change it to this:

```
$(document).replaceWith(jqueryObjectMinusImages);
```

It is working for me.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a16rberw/)

Comment: That does not work and you don't want to replace the entire document with a figure tag.